# Analysing English text with some French name

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm dealing with the Well-known novel of Victor Hugo "Les Miserables". 
A part of my project is to detect the existence of each of the novel's character in a sentence and count them. This can be done easily by something like this:

```
def character_frequency(character_per_sentences_dict,):
    characters_frequency = OrderedDict([]) 
    for k, v in character_per_sentences_dict.items():
        if len(v) != 0:
            characters_frequency[k] = len(v)
    return characters_frequency, characters_in_vol
```

This pies of could works well for all of the characters except "Èponine".

I also read the text with the following piece code:

```
import codecs 
import nltk.tokenize 

with open(path_to_volume + '.txt', 'r', encoding='latin1') as fp:                                                                        
   novel = ' '.join(fp.readlines())

# Tokenize sentences and calculate the number of sentences                                                                                    
sentences = sent_tokenize(novel)
num_volume = path_to_volume.split("-v")[-1]
```

I should add that the dictation of "Èponine" is the same everywhere.

Any idea what's going on ?!

Here is a sample in which this name apears:

" ONE SHOULD ALWAYS BEGIN BY ARRESTING THE VICTIMS 
At nightfall, Javert had posted his men and had gone into ambush himself between the trees of the Rue de la Bar­rieredes-Gobelins which faced the Gorbeau house, on the other side of the boulevard. He had begun operations by opening his pockets, and dropping into it the two young girls who were charged with keeping a watch on the ap­proaches to the den. But he had only caged Azelma. As for Èponine, she was not at her post, she had disappeared, and he had not been able to seize her. Then Javert had made a point and had bent his ear to waiting for the signal agreed upon. The comings and goings of the fiacres had greatly agi­tated him. At last, he had grown impatient, and, sure that there was a nest there, sure of being in luck, having recog­nized many of the ruffians who had entered, he had finally decided to go upstairs without waiting for the pistol-shot."

Comment: in what way is it not working?

Comment: @KevinWang the word "Èponin" exists at least twice with the dictation but the frequency of it is zero! And this made me really puzzled

Comment: Is specifying the encoding necessary? That may be causing the same word to be detected as different since the encoding of Python (3) is Unicode by default. Also, I'm assuming your working code is very different from this one, for several reasons including several keywords misspelled with uppercase initials and the "novel" variable not being used beyond its declaration.

Comment: You appear to be using raw string processing to detect high-level text entities like proper names. Please look at `nltk` (https://www.nltk.org/) which has sophisticated tools more suited to this task.

Comment: Did you get it working?  as @FedericoS said, have you tried not specifying encoding = 'latin'?  Is it python2 or python3?

Comment: @KevinWang here is the error I got when I run the code without any encoding:   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_miserables_v03.py", line 83, in <module>
    run_dataset(path_to_volume=volume_path)
  File "compute_miserables_v03.py", line 19, in run_dataset
    novel = ' '.join(fp.readlines())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 34: invalid start byte

Comment: @KevinWang about your first question, I tried it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BoarGules that there is likely a more efficient and effective way to approach this problem.  With that said, I'm not sure what your problem is here. Python is fully Unicode supportive.  You can "just do it" in terms of using Unicode in your program logic using Python's standard string ops and libraries.

For example, this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

names = [
    u'Éponine',
    u'Cosette'
]

# Retrieve Les Misérables from Project Gutenberg
t = requests.get("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-0.txt").text

for name in names:
    c = t.count(name)
    print("{}: {}".format(name, c))
```

Results:

```
Éponine: 81
Cosette: 1004
```

I obviously don't have the text you have, so I don't know if how it is encoded, or how it is being read is the problem.  I can't test that without having it.  In this code, I get the source text off the internet.  My point is just that non-ASCII characters should not pose any impediment to you as long as your inputs are reasonable.

All of the time to run this is spent reading the text.  I think even if you added dozens of names, it wouldn't add up to a noticeable delay on any decent computer.  So this method works just fine.

Comment: I've edited my question and also add a piece of text with the mentioned name. Any help is appreciated!